# modify HTTP request URI and HTTP request method with a CXF interceptor

Tags: http, cxf, httprequest, interceptor

I want to modify HTTP request URI and HTTP request method using a CXF interceptor in a HTTP client.

I have developed something like this:

```java
public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {    

    public MyInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL);
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            // this returns me correct path and method
            // String path = (String) message.getExchange().getOutMessage().get(Message.REQUEST_URI);
            // String method = (String) message.getExchange().getOutMessage().get(Message.HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD);

            // this does not work as expected
            String path = (String) message.get(Message.REQUEST_URI);
            String method = (String) message.get(Message.HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD);

            // do things here
    }

}
```

**Why do need I to use exchange/OutMessage to obtain data about current message and I can not use message directly?**

**How can I edit both values?** I tried using `message.put(<key>, <value>)` and the same with exchange/OutMessage, but nothing is modified.

Comment: Can you add some detail around how you are configuring the Interceptor?  It sounds like its being called as an InInterceptor and not an OutInterceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Coming to the path, you'd always get that value as null, I believe.
You can try following code, to get the actual value of your uri:

```
 String requestURI = (String) message.get(Message.class.getName() + ".REQUEST_URI");
```